# Is there an efficient way to load current location to react state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

Sorry if this seems like a silly question but I am stuck on using the navigator.geolocation JavaScript API.

I want to load the current user location to state when the component loads.

My state is

```
    state = {
     currentLatitude : '',
     currentLongitude : ''
    }
```

and my component mount is:

```
componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        console.log("Latitude is : ", position.coords.latitude);
        console.log("Longitude us : ", position.coords.longitude);
    });
  }
```

This logs the Latitude and Longitude to the console but when I try setting the latitude to state, I get an error, "cannot read property setState of undefined":

```
componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        this.setState({
            currentLatitude: position.coords.latitude, 
            currentLongitude: position.coords.longitude
        })
    });
}
```

I have also tried

```
   componentDidMount() {          
        this.setState({
            currentLatitude: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition.coords.latitude, 
            currentLongitude: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition.coords.longitude
        })
    }
```

But I get the same error.

The complete class component is:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Location extends Component {

state = {

    currentLatitude : '',
    currentLongitude : ''

}

componentDidMount() {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        console.log("Latitude is : ", position.coords.latitude);
        console.log("Longitude us : ", position.coords.longitude);
        console.log(position)
    });

}

handleChange = (e) => {
    localStorage.setItem([e.target.id], e.target.value)
    this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="location">
            <p>{this.state.currentLongitude}</p>
            <p>{this.state.currentLatitude}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

export default Location

Please assist on how to load this to the state.

Thank you.

Comment: I have never dealt with class components much, but I knew class components should always call the base constructor with props. And try the arrow function as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a callback function, `this` references to the context it is in when it is finally called. Use an arrow function to use the component context instead:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
    this.setState({
        currentLatitude: position.coords.latitude, 
        currentLongitude: position.coords.longitude
    })
});
```